# jquery code for many classes, map-1, map-2

Tags: jquery, html

I want this jQuery code to play for many maps, e.g. for `.map-1`, `.map-2`, `.map-3`.

**HTML :**

```
<div class="view-map" id="view-map">View Map</div>
<div class="map-1">
<div id="close" class="close-btn"></div>
</div>

<div class="view-map" id="view-map">View Map</div>
<div class="map-2">
<div id="close" class="close-btn"></div>
</div>
```

**jQuery :**

```
//when click on search toggle input
$("#view-map").click(function(){
    $(".map" + $(this).parent().attr("class")).css( "display", "block" );
  });

$("#close").click(function (event) {
    $(".map" + $(this).parent().attr("class")).hide();
});
```

Comment: Start by making your  id's unique. Using the view-map id several times will give you problems.

Comment: Why not give them all the classname `map`?

Comment: Beacause if i click #view-map displays all elements with class .map

Comment: Firstly, if you want the user to click on something, it's much better to use an `<a>` or `<button>` element. That's what they're for, after all! Secondly, rather than `.css("display", "block")`, why not just use `.show()`?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that you want to use a CSS class for this? If it's going to be unique, why not just make it an ID instead?

Anywho, you can chain selectors like this:

```
$(".map-1, .map-2")
```

Or if you're using IDs:

```
$("#map-1, #map-2")
```

Answer (score 1):

Call the functions based on class

```
//when click on search toggle input
$(".view-map").click(function(){
   ...
  });

$(".close-btn").click(function (event) {
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

IDs have to be unique! check this code:

Use a wrapper div to find the right map to show onclick!

```
<div class="map-wrapper">
   <div class="view-map" id="view-map1">View Map</div>
   <div class="map" id="map-1">
      <div class="close"></div>
   </div>
</div>

<div class="map-wrapper">
   <div class="view-map" id="view-map2">View Map</div>
   <div class="map" id="map-2">
      <div class="close"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

Use `show()` and `hide()` instead of your approach.
Find the parent which is the wrapper und look for the child map to show or hide!

```
//when click on search toggle input
$(".view-map").click(function() {
    $(this).parent(".map-wrapper").children('.map').show();
  });

$(".close").click(function() {
    $(this).parent(".map-wrapper").children('.map').hide();
});
```

Comment: html is this

<div class="article">
 <div class="desc">
   <button class="view-map" id="view-map">View Map</button>
 </div>
 <div class="map">
   <div id="close" class="close-btn"></div>
 </div>
</div>

i put this but don't work 
 $("#view-map").click(function(){
 $(".article").children('.map').show();
 });
 
 $("#close").click(function (event) {
 $(".article").children('.map').hide();
 });

Comment: I write an answer bellow

Answer (score 0):

Do like this  `$('.map-1 .map-2 .map-3')` and it should work.

But it is advisable to use unique `ID` such as `map1, map2, map3`. In this case you can  use wild card selector of jquery.

For ex: `$("[id^=map]")`, now this will work for all the ID's having 'map'

Answer (score 0):

you should use the same class for all your maps like this

**html**

```
<div class="map map-1">
<div id="close" class="close-btn"></div>
</div>

<div class="view-map" id="view-map">View Map</div>
<div class="map map-2">
<div id="close" class="close-btn"></div>
```

**JQuery**

```
$("#view-map").click(function(){
    $(".map").css( "display", "block" );
});
```